# Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "done")

Tags: linux, shell, unix, syntax-error

I copied a shell script of SeisUnix(SU), a Linux based program for seismic processing.

```
#! /bin/sh
#File: Nmigcvp2.sh
#       Create one panel for each migration velocity
#       Each panel has the same "fldr" value
#       The migration velocity is in key "offset"
#       Total number of panels is in key "nvs"
# Set messages on
##set -x
#================================================
# USER AREA -- SUPPLY VALUES
#------------------------------------------------
# Seismic files
indata=Nstack4.su # SU format
outdata=Nmigcvp.su # migration Constant Velocity Panels

# Migration variables
cdpmin=900      # Start CDP value
cdpmax=1300     # End CDP value
dxcdp=16.667    # distance between adjacent CDP bins (m)
smig=1.0        # stretch factor (0.6 typical if vrms increasing)
                # [the "W" factor] (Default=1.0)
vscale=1.0      # scale factor to apply to velocities (Default=1.0)
lstaper=20      # length of side tapers (traces) (Default=0)
lbtaper=100     # length of bottom taper (samples) (Default=0)
# Velocity panel variables
firstv=1400     # first velocity value
lastv=2000      # last velocity value
increment=200   # velocity increment
numVtest=100    # use to limit number of velocity panels
                # otherwise, use very large value (100)
#================================================
# Compute number of velocity panels
numV=`echo "( ( $lastv - $firstv ) / $increment ) + 1" |bc -l

if [ $numVtest -lt $numV ] ; then
        numV=$numVtest
fi

#------------------------------------------------
# FILE DESCRIPTIONS
# tmp1 = binary temp file of input data
#------------------------------------------------
cp $indata tmp1
migV=$firstv
echo " "

#------------------------------------------------
# Loop through Migration Constant Velocity Panels
# Each panel has the same "fldr" value
# Panel migration velocity is in key "offset"
# Total number of panels (numV) is in key "nvs"
#------------------------------------------------
i=1
while [ $i -le $numV ]
do

        echo " iteration number = $i Velocity = $migV"

        suwind < tmp1 key=cdp min=$cdpmin max=$cdpmax |
        sushw key=fldr a=$i |
        sushw key=offset a=$migV |
        sushw key=nvs a=$numV |

        sustolt cdpmin=$cdpmin cdpmax=$cdpmax dxcdp=$dxcdp \
                tmig=0 vmig=$migV smig=$smig vscale=$vscale \
                lstaper=$lstaper lbtaper=$lbtaper \
        >> $outdata
        i=`expr $i + 1`
        migV=`expr $migV + $increment`
done
#------------------------------------------------
# Remove files and exit
#------------------------------------------------
echo " "
echo " Output file = $outdata"
echo " "

rm -f tmp*
exit
```

When I run the script I get a syntax error.

```
./Nmigcvp2.sh: 33: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "done")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
numV=`echo "( ( $lastv - $firstv ) / $increment ) + 1" |bc -l`
```

You're missing a `` ` `` backtick char at end of line here. If you use a colored syntax editor it is easier to find this kind of syntax error.

In VIM for example use `set syntax`  & `colorscheme elflord`.
You can also numerate lines `set nu`.